# На работают горячие клавиши в pycharm на linux mint

Tags: linux, pycharm, клавиатура

Не могу воспльзоваться в pycharm прелестями горячих клавиш.
Операционная система linux mint (последняя версия этого года). Везде работает только ctrl+c,v,z,d. Я понимаю, что дело или с раскладкой, или настройкой в самой linux.
Раскладку клавиатуры стоит английская США. Пробовал английская британия, все равно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Vim Emulator в плагинах не включен? или он мешает или может быть где-то конфликт хоткеев пайчарма с циннамоном в «Настройки» - «Оборудование» - «клавиатура»

Comment: в настройках клавиатуры там я не нашел Vim Emulator. там только выбор раскладки. в итоге настроил свои горячие клавиши в пайчарме, коренную проблему не решил.